# How can we get Catergory / Term Creator

Tags: categories

How can we get the category creator id ? I have checked the tables of category/terms viz. wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy and wp_term_relationships. But there is no information about creator of the category... Is there any function which we can use ?

Comment: By "creator" you mean the user who created the category? If so, that information is not stored by Wordpress. You would have to write your own function for storing the user on category insert.

Comment: @mike23 - you should make that an answer

Answer (score 2):

By "creator" you mean the user who created the category? If so, that information is not stored by Wordpress.

You would have to write your own function for storing the user on category insert, maybe by hooking into the `create_term` function.